# How to make Flurry Session Lengths accurate & useful

Tags: ios, session, flurry

Flurry > Usage > Session Length (B) shows my median session length as 2.5 minutes.

It also shows the benchmark as much lower, which makes me feel good.

But, when you look at the my session length distribution, it tells a different story:
[image]

The bell curve data:

- a 1600 sessions -> 0-3 sec
- b 2000 sessions -> 3-10 sec
- c 3500 sessions -> 10-30 sec
- d 3200 sessions -> 30-60 sec
- e 6500 sessions -> 1-3 MINUTES
- f 7000 sessions -> 3-10 MINUTES
- g 5000 sessions -> 10-30 MINUTES
- h 1500 sessions -> 30+ MINUTES

1)  How do I keep flurry from tracking / including inaccurate sessions? (a - c, potentially h)

I've tried using a timedEvent too:

If I drill down into it: 
Events > Select Event > Tap "Event Duration" I get Avg Event Duration, which is a little better, but way hidden (no dashboard access).

[image]

This shows an average of roughly 4 minutes -- visually estimated.

The **real gold** seems to be *Avg Event Duration per USER*, which shows much more realistic data.

[image]

This tells me that my times are increasing, starting at an average of 10 Minutes and going up from there.  This is a dramatically different picture than the "2.5 min median session length" Flurry touts on my dashboard.

But because I'm doing the timed event rather than relying on Flurry's Session Length logic, I tend to question the accuracy.

In short, how do I get Flurry's session length to be more accurate and useful?

Or, how do I prove that my timedEvent is accurate?

platform: iOS.

note: I've seen threads about "setContinueSessionMillis".  But the default value is 10 seconds, which doesn't seem to be working here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dave from Flurry here.

So Flurry is showing that most of your sessions are in the ranges between 1 and 30 minutes, but that there are some very short sessions and some very long sessions too.  What makes you think that is not accurate or useful?

The median being 2.5 minutes is consistent with the distribution - look for what value has half the sessions less and half being more.  Also, the average being 4 minutes would also make sense as a smaller number of long sessions can bring up the average.  Average and median are different things.

Using a timed event should be fine also.  Average event time per user would include the duration of that event for a user across multiple sessions, so is not surprising that it is showing a greater average time than average session time.